# Convert bash line breaks to HTML line breaks; runs good in BASH, but not through shell_exec

Tags: php, html, sql, bash, sudo

I've created a web page that converts bash line breaks [\n] to HTML line breaks [< br />]. This works by having the web page call

```
shell_exec("bash /xxx/xxx/script.sh");
```

Inside the bash script.sh, it runs a series of SQL queries to replace the bash line breaks with html line breaks, allowing me to format the SQL data into an HTML based email.

```
`mysql -uXXX -pXXX -e "UPDATE tbl SET var = REPLACE(var, '\n', '<br />')" db`
```

When I run this bash script via Linux cli, it runs perfect, and the email it sends out uses HTML line breaks. But when I run the script via shell_exec, it just shows in plain text, the bash line break code [\n].

Here is a sample of the email output when running the bash script with PHP shell_exec.

```
[ var1 ]
test test test\ntest test test\n test some more
[ var2 ]
test test\ntest\ntest
```

And a sample when I run the bash script from linux.

```
[ var1 ]
test test test
test test test
test some more
[ var2 ]
test test
test
test
```

I know my other SQL queries work such as SELECT MAX(id) [grabbing the appropriate row and data fields]. Any idea as to why the same script runs perfectly fine under linux bash (to run SQL query, replacing line breaks), but not by calling it with PHP shell_exec? Am I missing something here?

*** httpd error log states:
   sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

and when I enable:
    sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Could this be a TTY issue since it's a command/script being called by user apache? If so, any work arounds?

Comment: I know this doesn't solve the problem in the way you're asking, but is your bash script sending out the email or is the output from `shell_exec` passed to the PHP script, which then sends out the message? If the latter, then you could use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) to do the newline->`<br>` tag conversion on the PHP side.

Comment: Is using `shell_exec` the best way to execute SQL queries in PHP? **Hint:** [no](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).

Comment: The `sudo` error message reveals that the problem is in code which you have not posted here. Your approach seems rather odd on the whole anyway. Why would you not do the substitution in PHP if that's what you are using?

Comment: @kojiro Although this is used internally, I think you're right. Time to brush up on my PHP and move away from BASH. For the others who responded to the question, many thanks.

Comment: @Nikita Just in case it's not clear, the word `no` in my previous comment is actually a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is that currently it's replacing the '\n' char, when you would like to escape the '\' char AND 'n' char. Try to change your request like this:

```
`mysql -uXXX -pXXX -e "UPDATE tbl SET var = REPLACE(var, '\\n', '<br />')" db`
```